# List view not scroll in android prelollipop version

Tags: android

Profile page contain collapsing layout, tab layout and view pager fragment.the list view scroll inside the view pager.If we scroll the list view outside the fragment it does not scroll in Pre-lollipop version but the recyclerview works fine if we scroll any place of the layout.

Here is my code

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
        tools:context="com.cogzidel.hotfuse.PostFragment">
        <!--<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button_back"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back_white"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/toolbar" />
    -->

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="No Posts for you" />




    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

yout TextView covers the complete visible area of parent as it height is

`android:layout_height="match_parent"`

change it to

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"` or any proper value
and then touch/scroll event will be delivered to your listView.

Then you will be able to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this instead of ListView.

```
package com.github.takahirom.nested_listview;


import android.content.Context;

import android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat;

import android.support.v4.view.NestedScrollingChild;

import android.support.v4.view.NestedScrollingChildHelper;

import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;

import android.util.AttributeSet;

import android.view.MotionEvent;

import android.widget.ListView;


public class NestedListView extends ListView implements NestedScrollingChild {

    private int mLastY;

    private final int[] mScrollOffset = new int[2];

    private final int[] mScrollConsumed = new int[2];

    private int mNestedOffsetY;

    private NestedScrollingChildHelper mChildHelper;


    public NestedListView(Context context) {

        this(context, null);

    }


    public NestedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        this(context, attrs, 0);

    }


    public NestedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {

        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        mChildHelper = new NestedScrollingChildHelper(this);

        setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);

    }


    /**

*

* @see android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView#onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)

*/

    @Override

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        boolean returnValue = false;


        MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(ev);

        final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            mNestedOffsetY = 0;

        }

        event.offsetLocation(0, mNestedOffsetY);

        int eventY = (int) event.getY();

        switch (action) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                int deltaY = mLastY - eventY;

                // NestedPreScroll

                if (dispatchNestedPreScroll(0, deltaY, mScrollConsumed, mScrollOffset)) {

                    deltaY -= mScrollConsumed[1];

                    mLastY = eventY - mScrollOffset[1];

                    event.offsetLocation(0, mScrollOffset[1]);

                    mNestedOffsetY += mScrollOffset[1];

                }

                returnValue = super.onTouchEvent(event);


                // NestedScroll

                if (dispatchNestedScroll(0, mScrollOffset[1], 0, deltaY, mScrollOffset)) {

                    event.offsetLocation(0, mScrollOffset[1]);

                    mNestedOffsetY += mScrollOffset[1];

                    mLastY -= mScrollOffset[1];

                }

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                returnValue = super.onTouchEvent(event);

                mLastY = eventY;

                // start NestedScroll

                startNestedScroll(ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL);

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                // TODO: fling

                returnValue = super.onTouchEvent(event);

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:

                returnValue = super.onTouchEvent(event);

                // end NestedScroll

                stopNestedScroll();

                break;

        }

        return returnValue;

    }



    // NestedScrollingChild

    @Override

    public void setNestedScrollingEnabled(boolean enabled) {

        mChildHelper.setNestedScrollingEnabled(enabled);

    }


    @Override

    public boolean isNestedScrollingEnabled() {

        return mChildHelper.isNestedScrollingEnabled();

    }


    @Override

    public boolean startNestedScroll(int axes) {

        return mChildHelper.startNestedScroll(axes);

    }


    @Override

    public void stopNestedScroll() {

        mChildHelper.stopNestedScroll();

    }


    @Override

    public boolean hasNestedScrollingParent() {

        return mChildHelper.hasNestedScrollingParent();

    }


    @Override

    public boolean dispatchNestedScroll(int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed,

                                        int[] offsetInWindow) {

        return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedScroll(dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, offsetInWindow);

    }


    @Override

    public boolean dispatchNestedPreScroll(int dx, int dy, int[] consumed, int[] offsetInWindow) {

        return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, consumed, offsetInWindow);

    }


    @Override

    public boolean dispatchNestedFling(float velocityX, float velocityY, boolean consumed) {

        return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedFling(velocityX, velocityY, consumed);

    }


    @Override

    public boolean dispatchNestedPreFling(float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedPreFling(velocityX, velocityY);

    }


}
```

And sample project is here.
https://github.com/takahirom/NestedListView/blob/master/nested-listview/src/main/java/com/github/takahirom/nested_listview/NestedListView.java